# get the current [controller] for webAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a dotnet web API application, I want to use the current controller name on multiple places. Right now I have:

I want to instead of having color everywhere I want to use the current controller name.

// ColorController.cs (How it is now)

```
namespace Application.Api.Controllers
{

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(Roles = "color:read")]
    public class ColorController : ControllerBase
    {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    [HttpPost()]
    [Authorize(Roles = "color:write")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromBody] Color model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
        return BadRequest("An error occured during saving color");
    }
```

// ColorController.cs (What I want)

```
namespace Application.Api.Controllers
{

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(Roles = "[controller]:read")]
    public class ColorController : ControllerBase
    {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    [HttpPost()]
    [Authorize(Roles = "[controller]:write")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromBody] Color model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
        return BadRequest("An error occured during saving [controller]");
    }
```

What is the best way to replace the [controller] statically when compiling the controller. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a property returning Controller name.

```
private string ControllerName1
{
  get
  {

    return nameof(ColorController).Replace("Controller", "");
  }
}
private string ControllerName2
{
  get
  {
    return this.ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName;
  }
}

public ColorController()
{
}
```

ControllerName1 can be used everywhere in your controller but ControllerName2 is not eligible to use in constructor. You can use them within Actions since ActionDescriptor is created after constructor method called. As for using referance type in Attribute, it is not possible as far as i know. You need to use a value type here that you cannot replace/refactor that part of your code.